# regular expression to find sentence

Tags: regex

Lets say I'm working in TextMate and I have a .txt file with this paragraph:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

I'm looking for a regular expression that will select whatever sentence the cursor currently lies in.

For example, if cursor is placed just after Lorem, then the first sentence will be selected. If the cursor is placed just before exercitation, then the second sentence will be selected, and so on.

Comment: One major caveat is differentiating between sentences and abbreviation periods. If you had a sentence `We went to go see Dr. Smith today.`, and you placed the cursor at "see", you would want it to include everything, right? Unless you can guarantee that there will be no sentences that will break your regex in that fashion.

Comment: Not possible because language is not regular.

Comment: Just assume any period is the end of a sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, anyway, if you can match a sentence with this (very limited) regex (that ignores all Mr., Mrs., etc.)

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z ,]+\.
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pdpiGoArXjutqOIi)

and if you can limit your search to the line/paragraph in which the cursor resides, then you know you've got the right sentence when the cursor-index resides between the start and end indexes of the match.